# It is not clear how the django date_hierarchy is supposed to work

Tags: django, django-models

I have a Django 2.0 model with a datetime field called 'created'. I set the date_hierarchy in the admin to that field. When I display the admin page, the date hierarchy appears as expected - April 2019, May 2019, June 2019. I have three items in the model, each with a created date in April, May, and June.

When I click on any one of the dates in the date_hierarchy link, I expect the admin page to change and only show one item, which has the same created date as the month I clicked. However, all three entries are still displayed. Is date_hierarchy not working properly, or is my expectation wrong?

I created a test model and admin to illustrate my question.

```
class Fred(Model):
    name = models.CharField('name', max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, verbose_name="date created")
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, verbose_name="last update") 

class FredAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    date_hierarchy = 'created'
    list_display = ('name', 'created', 'updated',)
```

So, the admin page looks like this

[image]

Three entries with three different 'created' dates. The data_hierarchy in the admin displays the 'all dates', 'April 2019', 'May 2019', and 'June 2019' links corresponding to the three created dates.

My expectation is that clicking on the 'April 2019' link will limit the admin display to only those elements in the Fred model with created dates in April. But alas, none of the model rows are displayed, as seen below. The same happens when I click either May or Jun links - no entries in the Fred model are displayed.

[image]

So, what is the expected operation of the date_hierarchy admin function? The behavior I am seeing does not appear to be very useful.

Note: this behavior of date_hierarchy is not what I originally described above. But that behavior (in my actual project) was not very useful, either! BTW, I am using the same Python 3.7 virtual environment and same mysql database (Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26, for Linux (x86_64)) as my main project. It was just easier to add this Fred model and FredAdmin to my project to illustrate my question than listing everything in my real models and admin pages.

Thanks!

Mark

Comment: Please post the codes you tried?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "post the codes you tried."  I just have date_hierarchy = 'created' in the model admin. My question is really how is the date_hierarchy supposed to work.

Comment: Post what you have in your models.py. At least we can know what you are talking about.

Comment: Please see updated original post.